# SQL_Before_Insert_Trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, sql-insert

we have the problem in the select clause. How can we control which users can access which documents and present this to a trigger.

Task:
Implement a trigger that guarantees that an entry (insert) in the "Access" table may only be made if the accessing user for the document belonging to the versionid is also entered in the "Access Permission" table.

```
create or replace trigger access_trg
before insert
on access
referencing new as newRow
for each row
declare accessvar varchar2(32);
begin
        dbms_output.put_line('enter access');
        dbms_output.put_line(':newRow.user = ' || :newRow.user);
        dbms_output.put_line(':newRow.version = ' || :newRow.version);
        dbms_output.put_line(':newRow.date = ' || :newRow.date);
        dbms_output.put_line(':newRow.art = ' || :newRow.art);

--------------------------???????????????---------------------------
--------------------------???????????????---------------------------
        Select z.version into accessvar from access-permission z
        where z.user = :newRow.user;
        

        if (:newRow.version in (accessvar))
        then
            dbms_output.put_line('Access');
        else if 
        raise_application_error(-54781, 'No Access');
        end if;
end access_trg





create table version (
  versionId varchar2(15) primary key,
  createdby references user(userId) not null,
  creatdate date not null,
  document references document(documentid) not null,
  text clob,
  unique (createdby, creatdate, document));

create table accesspermission (
  user references user(userid) not null,
  document references document(documentid) not null,
  primary key(user, document));



create table access (
  user references user(userid) not null,
  version references version(versionid) not null,
  date date not null,
  type varchar(10) check(type in ('new', 'read')),
  primary key (user, version, date));
```

[Tables with inserts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aGe8.png)

Comment: What is your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Certainly you have a problem with `SELECT`; apart from syntax error (table name shouldn't contain a "minus" sign; it's probably an "underline"), you are selecting a column (`version`) which does **not exist** in the `access_permission` table. It is difficult to suggest anything if data model you presented isn't correct.

I *presume* that - once you fix that - you might hit the `TOO_MANY_ROWS` error if table contains more than a single row for that `:newRow.user`. What to do? It depends; one option is to add another condition(s) to `where` clause, or to use aggregate function (such as `max`) and select the highest `version`, maybe to use `exists` ... can't tell.

Furthermore, you're raising error `-54781`; Oracle reserved `-20000` to `-20999` for us, developers. Your value is out of that range, so - you should change it.